# Reading HTTP headers

Tags: qt, qt4, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to connect my application with a web service and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774200/connecting-a-desktop-application-with-a-website) ,a user suggested to send custom headers back to my application.

I am using this code

```
void Coonnec::serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();

    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Reply error: " + reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Uploaded: " + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
        qDebug() << reply->rawHeaderList();
    }
    reply->close();
    bytes.clear();
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

from php i send this header

```
header('XAppRequest-Status: complete');
```

When running the application i can see that i get this header but i can't take the value of it cause

```
reply->rawHeader(bytes);
```

returns nothing.

How can i take the value 'complete'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to connect a slot to the `void QNetworkReply::metaDataChanged ()` signal of your reply.

The Qt doc says

> This signal is emitted whenever the metadata in this reply changes.
>   metadata is any information that is not the content (data) itself,
>   including the network headers. In the majority of cases, the metadata
>   will be known fully by the time the first byte of data is received.
>   However, it is possible to receive updates of headers or other
>   metadata during the processing of the data.

I do use web-services/client with Qt and I noticed that some header's information are not available when I expected it to be ! I had to 'wait' for this signal to check the header content.

Comment: `rawHeaderList()` returns this `("Date", "Server", "X-Powered-By", "XAppRequest-Status", "Content-Length", "Keep-Alive", "Connection", "Content-Type")`, so i think this is not the problem.

Comment: What the content of `bytes` in the `reply->rawHeader(bytes);` command ? Did you check if you are you passing the proper `headerName` ?

Comment: That was too obvious and as a result i didn't try it. It works using `reply->rawHeader("XAppRequest-Status");`.